Read CSV with epoch timestamp column as timestamp
I'm using pyarrow.csv to read and convert a CSV file to parquet. This CSV file has a timestamp column with an int representing Unix time.
Nevertheless, it reads it as an int64, and if I try to use convertoptions, it raises an error:
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.csv as pv

table = pv.read_csv("file.csv", convert_options=pv.ConvertOptions(
    column_types={
        'timestamp': pa.timestamp('s'),
    }
))

This raises the following error:
ArrowInvalid: In CSV column #1: CSV conversion error to timestamp[s]: invalid value '1705173443'


While I haven't found a way to directly read it from the CSV, I can use pyarrow.compute.cast to cast the integer to a timestamp:
table = table.set_column(
  # Put the new column in the same place than the old one
  table.column_names.index('timestamp'), 
  # Keep the same name
  'timestamp', 
  pc.cast(table['timestamp'], pa.timestamp('s'))
)


pc.cast(x[c], ...) is equivalent to x[c].cast(...)
